# Как передать в компонент название тега, который должен внутри отрендерится?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Доброго времени суток! Вопрос такой, мне надо во Vue компонент передать название html тега, и он должен этот тег добавить в свою разметку. Есть конструктор формы, выбираем инпут, и потом при просмотре результата видим тег инпут, если пользователь выберет селект - появится селект. Как реализовать?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй функцию `createElement` - передай ей

- имя тега
- атрибуты тега
- дочерние элементы

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42742761/4928642

Comment: Спасибо, да, я так и думал, но есть во vue другой способ, я уже вспомнил. Во vue есть директива v-html. Вчера вечером совсем про нее забыл и завис над задачей. Все равно, Спасибо!

Comment: держи плюс, для ровного счета)))))  Ну и за верный ответ)))))

Comment: Да, таки пришлось через createElement, v-html штука прикольная, но она работает с корневым каким-то тегом, и он остается как обертка, в моем случае эта обертка портила верстку... А createElement просто создаст нужный элемент. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Возможность создания элемента средствами нативного js это хорошо, но во Vue есть директива v-html, которая как раз может помочь в этом вопросе.